# Error connecting to MS Access database with pyodbc in Python

Tags: python, ms-access, ms-access-2010, pyodbc

Having trouble connecting to a MS Access database using pyodbc. I think I know what's causing the problem, I'm just not sure how to fix it.

I'm using 64 bit Access, 64 bit Python and my system is 64 bit. Here's my code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="c:/temp/data.mdb;')
```

Which produces the error:

```
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I think the reason for this has to do with the fact that (for whatever reason) when I go into my driver administrator (control panel -> system and security -> administrative tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)), it's looking in my **C:\Windows\System32** folder when it should be looking in my **C:\Windows\SysWOW64** folder. I dont have a working access driver in my \system32 folder, so it gives me an error.

**Question: How can I get pyodbc to look into my C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder, which has the Access driver I'm looking for?**

Similar to what happens when I go into the control panel to get to my driver administrator, pyodbc seems to be defaulting to the \system32 folder when it should be looking for the driver in the \systwow64 folder.

Comment: On 64-bit Windows, `\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` is the 64-bit ODBC Administrator. You should see `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` on the "Drivers" tab if you really do have 64-bit Access installed. You can use my [AceOdbcCheck](https://github.com/gordthompson/AceOdbcCheck) script to test your machine for a valid install of the Access Database Engine components.

Comment: I know I have 64-bit access installed and the driver seems to be installed in \Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. The ODBC Administrator in the System32 doesnt have a working Access driver

Comment: Have Windows Explorer search your hard drive for MSACCESS.EXE. If it lives under "Program Files" then it is 64-bit, but if it resides under "Program Files (x86)" then it is 32-bit.

Comment: The problem isn't whether or not my Access is 64 bit. It is. The problem is with pyodbc looking in the system32 folder when it should be grabbing the driver info from the SysWOW64

Comment: *"The problem isn't whether or not my Access is 64 bit. It is."* - I don't believe you. If the driver only appears in SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe then it is a 32-bit driver, strongly suggesting that you have 32-bit Access installed.

Comment: *"The problem is with pyodbc looking in the system32 folder when it should be grabbing the driver info from the SysWOW64"* - 64-bit Python will not be able to use a 32-bit driver. If you really do have the 32-bit driver installed then you'll need to use a 32-bit version of Python.